# New Year's Eve hat still not awarded?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

I have had two messages in chat starred multiple times:

- http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1227296#1227296
- http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1227343#1227343

Yet after ~11 hours I still have not received the hat even though others have it.

[image: newyearshat]

Is this all a big **lie** or am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** I have since had several of my messages starred in various rooms but *no* hat. There seems to be a secret to this.

**UPDATE 2:** After following mbinette's answer:

[image: newyearsevehat]

Comment: I've seen it awarded on meta, but not on SO.

Comment: @mbinette That was in chat.meta

Comment: I know. I'm just saying. He got it tho: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153001/scrooginator

Comment: @mbinette Yes, multiple people have it. It says "starred message" but I guess I will try anything

Comment: I'd created [a room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21909/testing-stuff) on chat.SO to test something, after having gotten the hat on meta. The first star (on my message), was via a pin/unpin, so that doesn't count-- but all the starred messages after that belong to users without hats. Something smells broken.

Comment: @Manishearth You got it. *GIVE IT TO ME*

Comment: Ah, I figured out the issue. Only I and mootinator have it on MSO for a reason. A simple one. We both know about the peculiarities of the chat for this site. Figure it out ;-)

Comment: @Manishearth - you can't leave a comment like that hanging in the wind.

Comment: @ChrisF ah well.  I wanted to have some fun first :p The reason is: the hats don't work for chat.SO and chat.MSO. Only for chat.SE (where there are rooms associated with SO/MSO)

Comment: @Manishearth - ah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you go the central [StackExchange chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com) and set up a room for the site you want the hat for.

Here are two I prepared earlier:

- Stackoverflow: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6904/stackoverflow-new-years-eve-hat
- Meta: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6905/meta-stackoverflow-new-years-eve-hat

Comment: @mbinette It definitely worked for me for both rooms. You can check the leaderboard for those sites and enter my name if you need proof. Or just look at the hat I'm wearing now :)

Comment: Alright then. Deleting my answer. I guess it makes sense, the mod rooms were probably created from SE chat sites.

Comment: Confirmed on SO. +1 :) Happy New Years!

Answer (score 7):

I just deployed the fix:

We were only awarding NYE hats for starred chat messages in chatrooms on the chat.stackexchange.com domain. Now, hats are also awarded for messages on chat.stackoverflow.com and chat.meta.stackoverflow.com as well.